# Form Validation not working on all fields but only the first

Tags: javascript, html, validation

When i post form only the title validation is working, the other two fields are not validated.

**HTML**

```
<form name="qaform" class="nice" method="POST" onsubmit="validateForm()" action="/ask/ask-question/">

            <input type="hidden" id="id_selected_tags" name="tags">
            <p>
                <label for="id_title" class="inline-block">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text inline-block" id="id_title" name="question_title">
            </p>
            <span id="error_title"></span>

            <textarea id="id_question" name="question_description" class="full-width"></textarea>
            <span id="error_body"></span>
            <p>
                <label for="id_tags" class="inline-block">Tags</label>
                <input type="text" id="id_newstagbox" name="question_tags"/>
            </p>
            <span id="error_tags"></span>

            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Post your question</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function validateForm()
{
//title validation

if (document.qaform.question_title.value == "") {
     document.getElementById('error_title').innerHTML="*Please add a title*";
      return false;
 }


//body validation
if (document.qaform.question_description.value == "") {
     document.getElementById('error_body').innerHTML="*Please add a description*";
     return false;
}

//tag validation
if (document.qaform.question_tags.value == "") {
     document.getElementById('error_tags').innerHTML="*Please add a description*";
     return false;
}

}
```

After submitting the forms post successfully if title is present.

*The stackoverflow form validation forced me to do this, its constantly saying me to add more text because my question contains mostly code.I know its good to provide more information about question but there are times when you can ask a question in few words without being too broad and then you have to rant about it to pass the FORM VALIDATION.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `return false`.modify it like below

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var y=document.forms["myForm"]["farea"].value;
var z=document.forms["myForm"]["ftag"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
   document.getElementById('ern').innerHTML="*Please add a title*";

  }
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
   document.getElementById('era').innerHTML="*Please add a desxription*";

  }
if (z==null || z=="")
  {
   document.getElementById('ert').innerHTML="*Please add a tag*";

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: even though it works, i.e shows error but the form gets submitted and page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You just remove your `return false` inside each condition,
**check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxkQ4/1/) how it works if  you remove return false line**.

Note:Return false will stop your execution there

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using jQuery:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
        var validated = true;
        e.preventDefault();

        //title validation
        if ($('#id_title').val() == "") {
            $('#error_title').html("*Please add a title*");
            validated = false;
         }

        //body validation
        if ($('#id_question').val() == "") {
            $('#error_body').html("*Please add a description*");
            validated = false;
        }

        //tag validation
        if ($('#id_newstagbox').val() == "") {
            $('#error_tags').html("*Please add a description*");
            validated = false;
        }

        if(validated) {
            $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "return false" in the if clauses. This stops your function and the other if clauses wouldn´t get called.

Answer (score 0):

just add 'return' keyword  before validateform()

like this

```
<form name="qaform" class="nice" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="/ask/ask-question/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making these 5 small changes to your validateForm method -

```
function validateForm() {
  var valid = true; // 1
  //title validation
  if (document.qaform.question_title.value == "") {
     document.getElementById('error_title').innerHTML="*Please add a title*";
     valid = false; // 2
  }

  //body validation
  if (document.qaform.question_description.value == "") {
     document.getElementById('error_body').innerHTML="*Please add a description*";
     valid = false; // 3
  }

  //tag validation
  if (document.qaform.question_tags.value == "") {
     document.getElementById('error_tags').innerHTML="*Please add a description*";
     valid = false; // 4
  }
  return valid; // 5
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think the reason why it only validates the first one, is because you return false to exit the validate function, if you do the return false after all the if loops i think it will do what you want.